# Chrome Network Request does not show Cookies tab, some request headers, Copy as cURL is broken

Tags: google-chrome

Since I upgraded to Chrome 72 the "Cookies" tab in Developer Tools -> Network -> A network request no longer shows the "Cookies" tab, and the request headers no longer include Cookies.

Furthermore, right clicking on a network request and selecting Copy -> Copy as cURL gives a `curl` command without the proper request headers / cookies.

See screenshots comparing Chrome with Cookies tab / request headers, and Chrome without them.

## It looks like this:

[image: Chrome without cookies tab]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I filed a bug report on the chromium project, and got an answer to disable <del>`chrome://flags/#site-isolation-trial-opt-out`</del> and `chrome://flags/#network-service`.

However, <del>`chrome://flags/#site-isolation-trial-opt-out`</del> may affect things such as vulnerability to Spectre-like attacks. So I did not disable it.

I did disable `chrome://flags/#network-service` and now it works properly.

## Now it looks like this:

[image: Chrome with cookies tab]

Comment: Tracked here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=868407

Comment: Chrome 75 - I'm suffering from the same problem, this solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Chromium 76. There is no #network-service. What worked for me was disabling #site-isolation-trial-opt-out.

Comment: It's in the Application tab now. Please look for the current chrome dev tools docs.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 78 fixes this, without the need for any special settings. It's out in Beta now (2019/9/19).

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 78 is out and fixes this: the tab "Cookies" is back